# Html Parser for PHP like Java

Tags: php, html-parsing

I have been developing Java programs that parse html source code of webpages by using various html parsers like Jericho, NekoHtml etc...

Now I want to develop parsers in PHP language. So before starting, I want to know that are there any html parsers available that I can use with PHP to parse html code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [DOMDocument](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php).

Example #1 Creating a Document

```
<?php
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML("<html><body>Test<br></body></html>");
echo $doc->saveHTML();
```

Answer (score 2):

The builtin class [DOM parser](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) does a very good job. There are many other [xml parsers](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php), too.

Answer (score 1):

DOM is pretty good for this. It can also deal with invalid markup, however, it will throw undocumented errors and exceptions in cases of imperfect markup so I suggest you filter HTML with HTMLPurifier or some other library before loading it with the DOM.